# How to fix the show/hide button on input change based on if/else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning jquery. I have an HTML & jquery code. I want to show the button only if my answer is true on input value otherwise it should stay hidden. Also, I want to show the questions on my screen. See, if anyone can help. thanks

```js
var random = Math.random();
var range = random * 2;
var incrment = range + 1;
var floor = Math.floor(incrment);
var ques1 = "what comes after 4?";
var ans = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bot").keyup(function() {
    if (ans == floor) {
      $("#pete").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("#pete").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="bot" required="required"></p>
<input type="submit" id="pete" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: in which case button and question need to show ?

Comment: The thing is that `ans = 5` will never equal `floor` (which always has a value of `1`).

Comment: @DevsiOdedra when I open the index.html then there should be question on top. then input type and if input value is true then button should show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `show()` and `hide()` functions and i dont know when your `floor` and `ans` will be equal.

```js
var random = Math.random();
    var range = random * 2 ;
    var incrment = range + 1;
    var floor = Math.floor(incrment);
    var ans = 5;

 floor=6; //for testing i gave
 $("#bot").keyup(function() {
    if (ans == $('#bot').val()) 
       $("#pete").show();
     else 
       $("#pete").hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label>What number comes after 4?</label>
<input type="number"  id="bot"  required="required"/>
    <input type="submit" id="pete" style="display:none;" >
```

Comment: Thanks. Also pls tell me how to show your questions on screen. So based on their answer button show.

Comment: @Hammad tell me what is your actual requirement? Questions you can give inside `<label>` in html right?

Comment: when I open the index.html then there should be the question on top. then input type and if the input value is true then the button should show

Comment: @Hammad check my solution.. happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for your requirement . 

Use `innerHTML` to priint the question in the screen and `.value` to obtain the value entered by user ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <p id="question"></p>
     <p>Name: <input type="text"  id="bot"  required="required"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="pete" style="display:none;" >
</body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var random = Math.random();

    var range = random * 2 ;

    var incrment = range + 1;

    var floor = Math.floor(incrment);
    var ques1 = "what comes after 4?";
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = ques1;
    var ans = 5;





      $("#bot").keyup(function() {
      var ansFromInput = document.getElementById('bot').value;
        console.log("ans , floor" , ans , ansFromInput);

        if (ans == ansFromInput) {
          $("#pete").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
          $("#pete").css("display", "none");
        }
      });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like that** ,

Here using class to hide the button, we can add and remove class to achieve that.

```js
var random = Math.random();
var range = random * 2;
var incrment = range + 1;
var floor = Math.floor(incrment);
var ques1 = "what comes after 4?";

var floor = 5;

$('#ques').text(ques1);
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  
  $('#bot').on('input',function(e){
  
    if ($('#bot').val() == floor) {
      $("#pete").removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $("#pete").addClass('hide');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label> <p id="ques"> </p> </label>
<p><input type="text" id="bot" required="required"></p>
<input type="submit" id="pete" class="hide">
```